# Dual boot - Screen glitch - Vertical lines

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, uefi, dualboot, nvidia

I have an [HP ENVY Laptop 15-ep0142tx](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c06880118), it is currently running Windows 10 Home (Version: 20H2 and Build: 19042.804). I wanted to install Ubuntu 20.04 by dual booting, but after booting into the bootable USB, I am getting a screen which displays only on the upper half and the lower half showing vertical lines (see image below)

[image: Screen after booting into the live USB]

I thought it was a bug and exit the installation. Booting directly into the live OS gave the result above. Thinking that it was an issue with the ISO (the SHA256 checksum checks out from the website), I tried booting Ubuntu 18.04, but it too gave no success as the glitch is still present (see image below)

[image]

My system has an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 with Max-Q design, the driver version on running `msinfo32` gives `27.21.14.5763`. The driver version on NVIDIA Control Panel is `457.63` (see screenshot below)

[image]

The output of `msinfo32` is shown below

[image]

I followed the [itsfoss tutorial on dual booting Ubuntu alongside Windows](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) till step 5 after which I faced this issue and couldn't go any further. I shut down the system and booted into Windows which is working fine.

Comment: Somehow the laptop uses a resolution and refreshrate that isn't working for Ubuntu and thus trying to make heads and tails of the signal, resulting in this weird stuff. Aside from the image squeezed in half and generating garbage, it should still work until you can change the resolution or provide a more capable driver.

Comment: @LPChip I set up Ubuntu 20.04 all the way through, and I’m currently able to attach an external display and work on it. However, the problem on my laptop display still persists (I currently disable it completely). I tried using different resolutions and refresh rates in settings, but none could fix the problem. Any idea if some `xrandr` command can help? Also, I think running on something like a low graphics mode could potentially fix this issue (I tried booting into an Xubuntu live USB in low graphics and it looked fine, but installing it still gave the same glitch).

Comment: I even tried [creating a new configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890839/how-can-i-change-resolution-using-xrandr) using `xrandr` for my default display (3840 x 2160). Still no success.

Comment: Sorry, I know too little of Ubuntu to assist you further. I just recognize this as a timing issue. No idea how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have fixed itself. I was running with `nomodeset` for a while and the latest update seems to have fixed the issue. Please refer to my [answer on NVIDIA Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/laptop-screen-blank-not-detected-for-460-73-01-hp-envy-15-ep0142tx/178646/6?u=123avneesh) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a patch for this problem.

> **Note**: The proposed solution may have unintended side effects [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/1639293/display-and-nvidia-driver-not-compatible)

Here's what I did

1. Set the system to start with `nomodeset`.

   - Run `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` (Could use any text editor)
   - Navigate to line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and set it to

     - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` if you want the system to output the splash (not quiet). This will output the status during boot (enabling detection of boot issues)
     - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` if you want a quiet boot.
2. Use the open source drivers

   - Open `Additional Drivers` under `Software & Updates` and set the `NVIDIA Corporation` driver to `X.Org X server -- Nouveau (open source)`.
3. Reboot your machine

This must boot up without the problems described in the question.

Comment: I’ve asked this on [NVIDIA forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/laptop-screen-blank-not-detected-for-460-73-01-hp-envy-15-ep0142tx/178646), let’s see how this goes.