# Display and NVIDIA driver not compatible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an [HP ENVY Laptop 15-ep0142tx](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c06880118), it is currently running a dual boot (Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10). The laptop display is a 4K display. I currently use a kernel parameter **nomodeset** for correcting a [problem I used to face](https://superuser.com/questions/1630188/dual-boot-screen-glitch-vertical-lines) earlier.
So now my `/etc/default/grub` file has `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`.

After doing that, the problem was addressed, but a new problem spawned. This is definitely a display manager issue because after boot I can access a CLI using `Ctrl + Alt + F2` but the GUI doesn't show up. The issue is

- When I use the `X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)` driver, the laptop display works but an external monitor attached to the HDMI port doesn't.
- When I use the `nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested)` driver, the laptop display doesn't work (remains blank after boot) but an external monitor attached to the HDMI port works (external monitor isn't 4K, but I guess that's not very relevant).

I need to use both the displays and need NVIDIA CUDA to work. I use xfce with Ubuntu (xubuntu 20.04), the display manager is `lightdm`. The laptop has an NVIDIA RTX 2060 Max-Q graphics card.

I have removed `quiet splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `grub` to inspect if there are any issues during boot. I found no errors, the last line is `Starting Light Display Manager...`

I can share logs and outputs on request. I am a newbie, but can run basic commands.

Comment: I’ve asked this on NVIDIA [forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/laptop-screen-blank-not-detected-for-460-73-01-hp-envy-15-ep0142tx/178646), let’s see how this goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have fixed itself. I was running with `nomodeset` for a while and the latest update seems to have fixed the issue. Please refer to my [answer on NVIDIA Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/laptop-screen-blank-not-detected-for-460-73-01-hp-envy-15-ep0142tx/178646/6?u=123avneesh) for more information.